# Routing information

Tags: routing, bgp, ospf, rip

I'm confused about routing:

There are a number of routing protocols. The ones I know are RIPv2 and OSPF.
They allow routers to communicate with each other and share routing information.

What about BGP? 
This protocol also allows communicate with each other, right? 
But do they also share routing information?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The whole point of a routing protocol is so routers can share routing information.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 types of routing protocols :-

IGP(Interior gateway protocol) -- (which work between same AS number (Same As number means devices managed by same admin or company)). IGP protocols are RIP, ISIS , OSPF, EIGRP. They are fast but are not much flexible and are not designed to handle thousands of routes.

EGP(Exterior Gateway protocol -- used to work between different AS number .It is slower than IGPs but are much more flexible and can handle lakhs of routes. example BGP.

And yes BGP do share routing info . :)

Comment: correction -- IGPs are designed to HANDLE thousands of routes

Comment: So I can say that all routing protocols allow routers to communicate with each other and share routing information?

Comment: yes all routing protocols helps to find the best path between different locations. All routing protocols share their respective kinds of routing information.

Comment: Just as a side note: the full Internet routing table is about half a million routes.  BGP handles that just fine.

Comment: @RonTrunk actually, it's around 700k IPv4 prefixes now. Multiply by the number of peers, and it's a f'ing huge number. IGP's generally don't scale well to large numbers of *routers*. BGP can scale to huge numbers, mostly because it doesn't need to know about every router (just the ones connected to it), and has the concept of a route-reflector

Answer (score 0):

The routing protocols can also be configured to share different levels of information between each other, ranging from just a single default route to the full known routing table.

Multinational corporations use this approach on their global networks to provide fast routing at the local sites and stable WAN connections across the internet.
 LAN-IGP <-> WAN-BGP <-> LAN-IGP